# Image in bootstrap card not on the right place when on phone

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an image in a bootstrap card in the second col.
Everything looks fine on desktop but when im switching to phone i don't like how its looking.

```
<div class="mt-5 container card w-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card-title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img class="img-fluid img-responsive" src="trees.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The image looks like this when viewed on phone and dekstop:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUwSz.jpg

can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For responsive you need to use `col-sm` , `col-md`, `col-lg`, `col-xl`. You can refer through [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) for Bootstrap grid

```
<div class="mt-5 container card w-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card-title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img class="img-fluid img-responsive" src="trees.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @johannes Glad that I could help you. Please upvote and accept my answer if you feel that was helpful. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

In bs4 if you just use `col` class then the classes will always be next to each other. You need to define on which (screen)size you want the column to have which size.

```
<div class="mt-5 container card w-100">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">Card-title</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <img class="img-fluid img-responsive" src="trees.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here all I changed is the number of the column, I say on smallest screens the column should take all 12 spaces. On md (medium) sizes (and up) it should only take 50% of the screen.

Documentation about [the grid system of bs4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), maybe you need some other breakpoints than `col-md-6` . Maybe you are also satisfied with `col-sm-6` . The important thing to take away from these answers is how to set up your grid with bootstrap because that's the whole point of using bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks, i will into it

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap 4 have changed.
Let's change class `col` to `col-md-6` to show 2 columns on Desktop.
`col-sm-6` to show 2 columns on Tablet or `col-sm-12` to show 1 column full with site. And put `col-12` to show full width size on Phone.